# Fit the screen size to two markers in android using mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using mapbox to show the map and get the route between two markers. Now I am trying to get the screensize fit to two markers. So what is the method to do that in mapbox with android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to accomplish this you need to create a `LatLngBounds` and then zoom to that location.

so using the latest SDK version, 4.0.0, you'd achieve this with this code:

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(first marker position)
                    .include(second marker position)
                    .build();

CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 10);
```

You can include as many `LatLng` as you'd like by including them within your bounding box. Hope this helps!